# How set tab 2 in a xamarin forms Tabbed Page as the default tab on startup

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app I am working on in xamarin forms it looks like this:

[image]

When the app loads the friends tab is the 1st tab to load how do I make it to where the snap tab is the 1st tab to load when the app starts up?

Here is my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppName;assembly=AppName"
            x:Class="AppName.HomePage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Friends" Title="Friends" Icon="firendstab.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:FriendPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage >
        <NavigationPage  x:Name="Snap" Title="Snap" Icon="snaptab.png">>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:CameraPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="Notes" Title="Notes" Icon="notetab.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:NotePage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

heres my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppName
{
    public partial class HomePage : TabbedPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();






        }
    }
}
```

I've searched google for the past 2 days so I thought it was time to ask!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access the enumerator of the `TabbedPage`'s children and advance its position two times to get your "second tab". Assign that page as your `CurrentPage`:

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var pages = Children.GetEnumerator();
    pages.MoveNext(); // First page
    pages.MoveNext(); // Second page
    CurrentPage = pages.Current;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CurrentPage = Children[2];
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to set "CurrentPage" property.

In code is something like

```
            TabbedPage tp = new TabbedPage();
            tp.Children.Add(new PageFriends());
            tp.Children.Add(new PageSnap());
            tp.Children.Add(new PageNotes());
            tp.CurrentPage = tp.Children[1];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I tried your code example and i get this error on the last line of code: Error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage' (CS0021) any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe tp.Children[1] but mine is only a sample using code. If you use  xaml I think you have to write something else to assign the second tab to CurrentPage property

Comment: this was helpful for me to arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 3):

For me, what I did was this:

```
  (this.Parent as TabbedPage).CurrentPage = (this.Parent as TabbedPage).Children[2];
```

because in my tabbed page, I added my pages like this

```
this.Children.Add(new Landing());
this.Children.Add(new Categories());
this.Children.Add(new Collections());
this.Children.Add(new Options());
```

The above code snippets, will lead me to the Collections Page.